# Issues scraping ASCII art from a webpage

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am working on a project to scrape ASCII art from a website and have encountered a few instances in which I am unable to scrape certain pieces of text.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

site = "https://www.asciiart.eu/television/star-trek"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site))
categories = doc.css(".asciiarts pre")
puts categories[19]
```

For instance, running this code returns this incomplete image

```
ruby main.rb
<pre class="pre-LG">                     .......................... 
                 ................................... 
              ......................................... 
            ............................................. 
           ................................................ 
          .................................................. 
         .................................................... 
         ......;%;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%;%%.............. 
         .....;%%%;;;;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%;;;;%%%%..............% 
         .....%%%%%%%%;;;%%%%%%%%%%%%;;;%%%%%%%%%............%%% 
         /....%%%%%%%%%%%%;%%%%%%%%;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%..........;%%% 
         //...%%%a@@`  '@%%//%%%%%%%%@`  '@@a%%%%%%........;%/%% 
         //...%@@@@@aaa@@@%//%%%%%%@@@@aaa@@@@@%%%%%......%%/%% 
         //...%%%%%%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%....%%/%%% 
          //..%%%%%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%...%%/%%% 
           //.%%%%%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%..%%/%%% 
            //%%%%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%..%/%%% 
             ;%%%%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%;/%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.%%% 
               %%%%%%%%%//%%%%%%%%%%%;/%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
                %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%/ 
                 ;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%// 
                   %%%%%&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&lt;</pre>
```

Could anyone help me determine if this is an issue with my selectors or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The page is not valid HTML because `<` characters inside `pre` tags are present as is. They should be escaped as `&lt;`. So it looks like Nokogiri is unable to parse the page because of this problem.

Here is a quick and dirty workaround:

#### Version 1

```
# Read page and replace "illegal" less-than sequences with their proper HTML entity
page = open(site).read.gsub(/(<<+)/) { '&lt;' * $1.length }

# Now we can parse it properly
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
categories = doc.css(".asciiarts pre")
puts categories[19].text
```

#### Version 2

Like Jörg W Mittag pointed out this is fundamentally a lost cause, because the problem is on the website and not in our code. However, since the `pre` tags seem to be very consistently formatted, we could TRY and capture their full content and then use the `HTMLEntities` [gem](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities) to try and re-encode their content.

Note that this is a brittle implementation, but since the `pre` tags are consistently incorrectly encoded on that page, this will work for now. If some of the tags would be correctly encoded, and some not, this will not work. You will be fighting an uphill battle if that happens, but for now this works:

```
...
require 'htmlentities'

site  = "https://www.asciiart.eu/television/star-trek"
coder = HTMLEntities.new

page = open(site).read

# Fix all pre tags by forcibly re-encoding their content    
page = page.gsub(/(<pre.*?>)(.*?)(<\/pre>)/m) {
  pre_start = $1
  content   = coder.encode($2)
  pre_end   = $3

  "#{pre_start}#{content}#{pre_end}"
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
categories = doc.css(".asciiarts pre")
categories.each { |c| puts c.text }
```

Comment: This works great but now I am unable to implement it so that I can catch <, >, and &, as all three are causing the same issue. Would you have any recommendations for that?

Comment: @SamMcKenzie: The solution for those characters is exactly the same as the solution that was already presented to you. Just implement the solution that Casper showed you for `<` also for `>` and `&`. However, this is *fundamentally* a lost cause. The website is broken. It needs to be fixed on *their* end, there is nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: @SamMcKenzie See my edit. I added another option.